# Max function with variable number of arguments

Tags: c++, beginner, variadic, c++20

I find it irritating that in standard C++ I can't do `std::max(a, b) = x` when it's possible and that it can't handle more than 2 arguments. For the second concern I found [this `std::min` tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z_fnMdzfWAQ&t=266s) and it looks interesting but the usage of pointers confuses me because I don't understand why they are needed here. Since I want to learn more about c++ I wanted to try to create my own version of `std::max` while making use of the latest c++ features that I know of.

First I want to make use of concepts to let the user know when the types of arguments are invalid at compilation time:

```cpp
namespace std1 {

// Helper concept for static_assert
template<typename>
concept False = false;

template<typename T>
concept Boolean = std::is_same_v<T, bool>;

template<typename T>
concept TypeLessThanComparable = requires(T a, T b) {
    { a < b } -> Boolean;
};

template<typename T>
concept TypeLessThanEqComparable = requires(T a, T b) {
    { a <= b } -> Boolean;
};

template<typename T>
concept TypeGreaterThanComparable = requires(T a, T b) {
    { a > b } -> Boolean;
};

template<typename T>
concept TypeGreaterThanEqComparable = requires(T a, T b) {
    { a >= b } -> Boolean;
};
```

These are the functions themselves:

```cpp
template<typename T>
constexpr decltype(auto) max(T&& a) noexcept
{
    return std::forward<T>(a);
}

template<typename T>
constexpr decltype(auto) max(T&& a, T&& b) noexcept
{
    if constexpr(TypeLessThanComparable<T>) {
        return a < b ? std::forward<T>(b) : std::forward<T>(a);
    }
    else if constexpr(TypeLessThanEqComparable<T>) {
        return a <= b ? std::forward<T>(b) : std::forward<T>(a);
    }
    else if constexpr(TypeGreaterThanComparable<T>){
        return a > b ? std::forward<T>(a) : std::forward<T>(b);
    }
    else if constexpr(TypeGreaterThanEqComparable<T>) {
        return a >= b ? std::forward<T>(a) : std::forward<T>(b);
    }
    else {
        // if I just put false in static_assert it gives a compilation error no matter what
        static_assert(False<void>, "You called max with invalid arguments, cannot find comparison operators for their type");
    }
}

template<typename T, typename...Ts>
constexpr decltype(auto) max(T&& a, T&& b, T&& c, Ts&&...d) noexcept
{
    return max(a, max(b, max(c, d...)));
}

} // namespace std1
```

And some tests:

```cpp
struct A{};

struct B
{
    bool operator<(B const&) const noexcept = delete;
    bool operator<=(B const&) const noexcept = delete;
    bool operator>(B const&) const noexcept = delete;
    bool operator>=(B const&) const noexcept;
};

int main()
{
    static_assert(std1::max(1, 2) == 2);

    int a = 1;
    int b = 5;
    int c = 3;
    int d = 2;

    assert(std1::max(a, b, c, d) == b);

    std1::max(b, c, d) = 4;

    assert(b == 4);

    // This gives a compilation error because the static assertion failed
    // (void)std1::max(A{}, A{});

    // This works
    std1::max(B{}, B{}, B{}, B{}, B{});
}
```

I want to know if the code is well written and could replace `std::max` in c++20, maybe it has bugs that I'm not aware of since I am inexperienced in c++. You could also check the compiler explorer link: https://godbolt.org/z/5urgqR.

Comment: What's wrong with [`constexpr T std::max( std::initializer_list<T> ilist );`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max#top)?

Comment: @TobySpeight Can it do `std::max({a, b, c}) = 4`? It also doesn't pass my test with `B{}` when not all comparison operators are implemented.

Comment: Ah, I missed that you wanted an `lvalue` return type.  Thanks for the clarification.  There might be a way to use `std::reference_wrapper` to get that behaviour; as for types that don't implement `<` - I'd call that a bug in the type (but it's easy to pass a custom comparator).  I'll write this in an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this function is unnecessary.

We can deal with defective classes (that don't properly implement the standard `LessThanComparable` concept) by either fixing them (preferable) or by providing a comparator argument to `std::max`:

```
auto const b_lessthan = [](const B& a, const B& b){ return !(a>=b); };

std::max({B{}, B{}, B{}, B{}, B{}}, b_lessthan);
```

Sure, you could make a generic adapter using the same `if constexpr` chain as in this code, but are the defective types really that common?

---

We can arrange for `std::max()` to return an lvalue by passing it an initialiser list of `std::reference_wrapper` for its arguments:

```
template<typename... T>
constexpr auto& ref_max(T... args)
{
    return std::max({std::ref(args)...,}).get();
}
```

---

We now have

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::max(1, 2) == 2);

    int a = 1;
    int b = 5;
    int c = 3;
    int d = 2;

    assert(std::max({a, b, c, d}) == b);

    ref_max(b, c, d) = 4;

    assert(b == 4);

    // This gives a compilation error because the static assertion failed
    // (void)std1::max(A{}, A{});

    // This works
    auto const b_lessthan = [](const B& a, const B& b){ return !(a>=b); };

    std::max({B{}, B{}, B{}, B{}, B{}}, b_lessthan);
}
```

Which isn't so very different than the `main()` in the question.

Comment: You are right. Only now did I realize I should have added the possibility to provide a custom comparator so that the function can be useful. What I would add is an extra constraint, for example `Callable<T, F>`,  so that the comparator is actually valid so that the compiler won't give cryptic error messages.

Comment: Or do what `std::max()` does, and pass an iterator list and a comparator as the two arguments (but I'm not quite sure whether we can combine that with the fold expression for reference-wrapping).